# Transfer Function in Dynamic Linear Model to Quantify Intervention Effect?

Tags: r, structural-change, dynamic-regression

I have a time series consisting of 48 quarterly observations, relating to the area of land that was subject to development. I am trying to investigate whether a change in policy after 2011 caused an increase in the rate of land loss through an interrupted time series.

I have used a segmented regression approach, but find that the models are not a particularly good fit and have therefore explored the use of ARIMA models instead. From reading I gather that ARIMA models have been used to quantify intervention effect with transfer functions. I wondered whether anyone could help me to apply the same concept to a dynamic linear model?

I have copied the dataset below:

```
    time    var             Kalman smoothed Est  Intervention
1     1  5.365271            4.990629            0
2     2  6.283395            4.990629            0
3     3  3.496063            4.945248            0
4     4  4.804306            4.737774            0
5     5  7.703178            4.680711            0
6     6  2.738879            4.608677            0
7     7  3.633379            4.161798            0
8     8  3.178281            3.887281            0
9     9  3.410159            3.643520            0
10   10  1.089162            3.456114            0
11   11  3.736931            3.274275            0
12   12  3.513415            3.357124            0
13   13  3.816926            3.393966            0
14   14  3.420433            3.416340            0
15   15  3.143683            3.390189            0
16   16  2.671691            3.360374            0
17   17  4.087779            3.356808            0
18   18  3.588060            3.436232            0
19   19  3.075624            3.436732            0
20   20  3.638734            3.418902            0
21   21  5.318876                  NA            1
22   22  2.800017                  NA            1
23   23  4.169757                  NA            1
24   24  3.283836                  NA            1
25   25  2.653585                  NA            1
26   26  4.321672                  NA            1
27   27  4.157134                  NA            1
28   28  6.628067                  NA            1
29   29  7.790614           10.834847            2
30   30  6.945923           10.834848            2
31   31 18.011305           10.916824            2
32   32  8.944063           11.105731            2
33   33  8.798605           11.108682            2
34   34 12.707824           11.169923            2
35   35  9.481303           11.295019            2
36   36 10.396044           11.382071            2
37   37 10.198316           11.520307            2
38   38 10.197405           11.688818            2
39   39 12.099243           11.897466            2
40   40 15.161557           12.151894            2
41   41 15.408401           12.407740            2
42   42  8.419664           12.589430            2
43   43 21.059561           12.695210            2
44   44 12.229320           12.916123            2
45   45  8.350715           12.917746            2
46   46 12.520039           12.937907            2
47   47 11.734633           13.081594            2
48   48 20.842981           13.240403            2
```

A dummy intervention variable is code 0 for the pre-policy period, 1 for a transitional period that will be excluded and 2 for the post-policy period.

If anyone has any ideas it would be a huge help.

Cheers